# How can I select an element which appears in popup window using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I  have selected the popup window using cssSelector 
ex:

```
WebElement a = TestApp.getInstance().getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("#PopupWindow0")) ;
```

now I want to select an element which is inside this popup.

Comment: The popup is HTML on the page like any other HTML. The only difference would be if some content is in an `IFRAME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you retrieved WebElement 'a' you can call `.findElement` on it, for example:

```
a.findElement(By.id("example"));
```

This will search for all elements inside the pop-up window